# Validation with loops

Tags: java, validation, date, loops

I need help figuring out to intakes a complete date and then validate that it is a real date.

This is what I have so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class numerology
{
     public static void main( String args[])
        {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            int month = 0;
            int date = 0;
            int year = 0;

            char slash = '/';

            int checker = 0; //a flag used to tell if the birthday enter is a validate one 0 = no 1 = yes

            System.out.println ("Enter birthday(mm/dd/yyyy): ");                                
                month = input.nextInt();
                slash = input.next().charAt(0);
                date = input.nextInt();                            
                slash = input.next().charAt(0);                                                 
                year = input.nextInt();

      while (checker == 0)
            {
                if ( month < 1 || month > 12)
                {
                    System.out.printf("Bad month: %d\n", month);
                    System.out.print("Re-enter birthday(mm/dd/yyyy): \n");                       
                       month = input.nextInt();
                       slash = input.next().charAt(0);
                       date = input.nextInt();
                       slash = input.next().charAt(0);
                       year = input.nextInt();

                }
                else
                if ( slash != '/')
                {
                    System.out.print ("Use forward slash");
                    System.out.print ("Re-enter birthday(mm/dd/yyyy): ");
                    month = input.nextInt();
                    slash = input.next().charAt(0);                   
                    date = input.nextInt();                                                
                    slash = input.next().charAt(0);
                    year = input.nextInt();
```

I got more code that checks the date and year but I'm aready running into problems with the code I have now.

My problem at the moment is that the check '/' won't work.

Also when I run this loop, there is no way to exit it (it's an infinite loop). It's obviously a problem that I still am not able to solve for over a week of working on this. I have been trying to find a way to use the Int "checker" to somehow turn to a 1 so the loop will exit. However no luck on figuring that out either. So bascially should I scrap this entire thing and start over? If so, can someone point me in the right directions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set `checker = 1` somewhere inside your loop so that the condition in the while loop becomes false and the code will exit

Comment: but if I set the int checker inside the loop that still won't help validate that the entire date is correct will it? I mean won't the checker be set to 1 no matter if a validate day is enter or not, it would just excute along with the rest of the loop.

Comment: I don't know if I understood your comment completely. But the `checker` variable won't be set to 1 unless you code it explicitly. You should add an `else` clause to do that assignment.